# I want to display an image on a grid view column if it is null and other image if its not null

Tags: c#, .net

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Assigned Tag" DataField="NBFCTagID"/>
```

If value of NBFCTagID is null then I want to display `red_mark.jpg` else `green_mark.jpg`.

I already tried `<imagefield>` but it wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add template field  like this.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Image ID="imgStatus" runat="server" CssClass="label" ImageURL='<%# GetImage((object)Eval("NBFCTagID")) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>



 public static string GetImage(object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        { 
            return "../Images/green_mark.jpg";
        }
        else
        {
            return "../Images/red_mark.jpg";
        }
    }
```

Comment: It shows invalid cast exception in .aspx page @mwisnicki

Comment: use `public static string GetImage(object value)` instead of `int` and then cast

Comment: still shows the same exception "System.InvalidcastException"

Comment: In image tag also changed? Should be like this <%# GetImage((object)Eval("NBFCTagID")) %>

Comment: its showing the green_mark image even when the value is null. :(

Comment: Try debug your app and check GetImage() method. In my app its working very well.

Comment: I cast the object to string and now it works fine. Thankyou. :)